# Bootstrap table radius reset

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, html-table

I wanted to reset the borders for bootstrap table and it worked on three borders {up, right, down} but on the left I still see some radius, how can I remove this radius?

You can find my code:

http://jsfiddle.net/yabasha/TGBtF/6/

```
.table {
   -webkit-border-radius: 0px;
    -moz-border-radius: 0px;
    -o-border-radius: 0px;
    border-radius: 0px;
}
td.tcenter {
    text-align: center;
    width: 144px;
    height: 90px;
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

---

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row-fluid">
        <div class="span12">
            <table class="table table-bordered">
                <tr>
                    <td class="tcenter"><img style="-webkit-user-select: none" src="https://mdn.mozillademos.org/files/3563/HTML5_Logo_128.png"></td>
                    <td class="tcenter"><img style="-webkit-user-select: none" src="https://lh5.googleusercontent.com/-8UcXZv4ucmI/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAAEk/4pvjZh57uqA/photo.jpg"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="tcenter"><img style="-webkit-user-select: none" src="http://wijmo.com/files/img/html5-blue.png"></td>
                    <td class="tcenter"><img style="-webkit-user-select: none" src="http://www.html5tests.com/img/blockdevice.png"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="tcenter"><img style="-webkit-user-select: none" src="http://www.html5developer.opensourcetechnologies.com/images/mobile_app.png"></td>
                    <td class="tcenter"><img style="-webkit-user-select: none" src="http://0.gravatar.com/avatar/8e88914e9976114748db6f525144b609?s=64&amp;d=retro&amp;r=R"></td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

http://jsfiddle.net/TGBtF/8/

```
  .table-bordered thead:first-child tr:first-child > th:first-child, .table-bordered tbody:first-child tr:first-child > td:first-child, .table-bordered tbody:first-child tr:first-child > th:first-child{
    border-radius:0;
}
.table-bordered thead:last-child tr:last-child > th:first-child, .table-bordered tbody:last-child tr:last-child > td:first-child, .table-bordered tbody:last-child tr:last-child > th:first-child, .table-bordered tfoot:last-child tr:last-child > td:first-child, .table-bordered tfoot:last-child tr:last-child > th:first-child{
border-radius:0;
}
.table-bordered thead:first-child tr:first-child > th:last-child, .table-bordered tbody:first-child tr:first-child > td:last-child, .table-bordered tbody:first-child tr:first-child > th:last-child{
border-radius:0;
}
.table-bordered thead:last-child tr:last-child > th:last-child, .table-bordered tbody:last-child tr:last-child > td:last-child, .table-bordered tbody:last-child tr:last-child > th:last-child, .table-bordered tfoot:last-child tr:last-child > td:last-child, .table-bordered tfoot:last-child tr:last-child > th:last-child{
    border-radius:0;
}
```

Comment: I have even tried `*{ border-radius: 0 !important; }` with no luck :/